# Remove duplicates based on a value in column of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Senario         
        


key              associated_keys                                    value      associated_value
KP6070  KP706010/KP706020/KP706030/KP706040/KP706050/KP706060/   AFE.706070.KP    AFE.706010.RT
KP6650  KP706610/KP706620//KP706630/KP706640/KP706650            AFE.706650.KP    AFE.706010.RT
```

python scripts I tried.

```
Deduptest.groupby(['associated_keys']).max()['associated_value'].reset_index()


Deduptest.drop_duplicates(['associated_value'],keep= 'first')
```

expected out

```
key                     associated_keys                               value    associated_value
KP6070  KP706010/KP706020/KP706030/KP706040/KP706050/KP706060/   AFE.706070.KP    AFE.706010.RT
```

I'm trying to remove duplicates based on `associated_value` column and `associated_keys`. If the value in `associated_keys` is already there in any others rows in that column and for both of those rows if the `associated_value` column data is same then I want the row with either the highest length or more data in it.

I tried `drop_duplicates` and I tried to use length function but i keep getting both the rows in my output.

Comment: how about the `.groupby` on those two columns?

Comment: Please post some code, are you using pandas, pyspark...?

Comment: please put an example of the output you want

Comment: I'm using Pandas

Comment: But `associated_keys` is different for both rows. Do you mean a duplicate only based on column `associated_value`?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, yes. But I need the first row as it has max values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# set up the key to get proper order
df["sort_key"]=df["associated_keys"].str.len()

# sort by that key
df.sort_values("sort_key", inplace=True, ascending=False)

# drop, keeping only the first record (in sorted dataframe, so the one with highest Len)
df.drop_duplicates(subset="associated_value", keep="first", inplace=True)

# drop sort column
df.drop("sort_key", axis=1, inplace=True)
```